# Can no longer access NAS on clean install of 20.04

Tags: samba, 20.04, nas

I did a clean install of 20.04. In files I can see my NAS but can't access it as it does not give the password dialog box.

There are other posts saying to modify the `smb.conf` file to make this work but I don't seem to have this file with a fresh install. Is there a way to fix this or is this version of Ubuntu basically useless to anyone with an older but perfectly functional NAS?

Comment: What is SMB protocol version on NAS? With SMBv1 there are too many problems with Ubuntu 20.04. It’s deprecated protocol. https://www.samba.org/samba/history/samba-4.11.0.html

Comment: The NAS is v1 and I know it is outdated and that there are security issues. That doesn't change the fact that you should have an option to access it. Even Windows gives you the option. I have no issue modifying the SMB.conf file like most posts about this are saying but with a clean install that file doesn't exist. Is there any other way of enabling v1?

Comment: For me, it is now solved after today's (may 21) Ubuntu upgrade to 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.2.
With full samba installed and "client min protocol = NT1" add to smb.conf I can mount the NAS share and the objects (avi, jpg, etc.) are seen and treated properly as objects not as folders.
I haven't tried with just samba-common installed.

Comment: I found this article very helpful in resolving my issues with setting up SMB Server in Ubuntu 20.04 lts with a static IP, and mapping the shared drive in Windows 10 Enterprise: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-samba-server-share-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux The main issues that resolved the connection were with turning on the MS Services that were inactive by default.

Answer (score 3):

One way to resolve this issue in Samba:

Edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

That file will be added when you install either the `samba` package or the `smbclient` package. If you don't want to install samba install smbclient:

```
sudo apt install smbclient
```

Then edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and right under the workgroup = WORKGROUP line add this one:

```
client min protocol = NT1
```

Another way - and one I prefer myself - is a cifs mount.

Comment: For many people with router from a ISP, this solution did not work until  today's (may 21) Ubuntu upgrade to samba 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.2.
With the previous samba version all  the objects (avi, jpg, etc.) in the NAS share were seen and treated as folders.

Answer (score 1):

I added these **two** lines to `smb.conf` in the `[global]` section and that fixed it for me on Xubuntu 20.04.

```
client min protocol = NT1 

server min protocol = NT1
```

More details are given here: [Broken samba shares](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2432909)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work on Gnome 3.36 Ubuntu 20.30.
You can mount and access the NAS share but every object (avi, jpg etc.) is seen as a folder!

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with 20.04 accessing NAS share.
You can check if you have an old Ubuntu 18-19 live dvd: it can access NAS share out of the box without tweaking anything.

In 18-19 and 20.04, only samba.lib, cifs.lib, nfs.lib are installed. It's sufficient in 18-19 but it does not work for NAS share in 20.04.
So the solutions commonly found (full cifs, full samba, full nfs) all miss the point: you did not need to do any tweaking in 18-19.

Smb.conf is installed if you install FULL samba for directory sharing (other than NAS) for instance and it works well in 20.04. In Gnome 3.36, if you share a folder, it installs full samba automaticaly and it works out of the box in 20.04. But you won't be able to acccess NAS shares or if you can the objects (avi, jpg, text etc.) are all seen as folders.
This behaviour is a known bug suppposedly recently solved. (Page bottom)
https://launchpad.net/~sergiodj/+archive/ubuntu/samba-bug1872476-v2

Answer (score 0):

add
`client min protocol = NT1` into `/etc/samba/smb.conf` following `[global]`part

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sergiodj/samba-bug1872476-v2`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Please explain, what that `add-apt...` command does and why it helps.

Comment: This comment refers to a discussion on a bug. If you add  client min protocol = NT1 to smb.conf after a full samba install, you may access the NAS share but every objet is seen as a folder. So it's useless. In the discussion, someone is mentionning a PPA (a repository) solving the problem, for the sake of discussion. They say the solution is coming. Adding PPA's is not a great idea for security reasons.
It's a widespread bug waiting for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

i've got a simple solution for newbies.
step 1: instal smb4k with the standard software installer from 20.04. Step2 run smb4k several times and then shut it completely down. You now have a etc/samba directory with a smbconf file. step 3 Go to terminal and give in line "sudo nautilus" Your file browser starts up with root authority. Navigate to etc/samba and open smbconf file. You can now ad the line"client min protocol" to the global chapter of the smbconf file. I prefer it as the last line of the chapter. safe the file. Step 5. run smb4k again so smb is restarted. now you can open your old fashioned NAS. It works for mee Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem and only wanted to install the bare minimum to get this going, so this is what I did.

Installed `cifs-utils` (uses 306kB when Installed), rebooted (not sure if this was really required but I did this anyway), then mounted the file system manually. My NAS is fairly old, my first attempt failed; I used `dmesg` to see the kernel messages, it showed me this:

```
[  421.153221] FS-Cache: Loaded
[  421.175272] FS-Cache: Netfs 'cifs' registered for caching
[  421.184044] Key type cifs.spnego registered
[  421.184049] Key type cifs.idmap registered
[  421.184590] CIFS: Attempting to mount //nas01/share
[  421.184612] No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
[  421.212003] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

So I added the `vers=1.0` option to the mount command, and everything worked fine.

cifs-utils provides the mount.cifs command that allows the nas share to be mounted. The coercion to use protocol version 1.0 is required because the version 2 or 3 is now prefered (and the new default) due to a security hole, but as you mentioned "I'm on my own network, and I just wanted it to work".

Here is the recipe :

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils
# reboot
sudo mount -t cifs //nas01/share /mnt/nas01_share/ -o user=myusername,pass=mypassword,vers=1.0
```

This method doesn't help with nautilaus mounting the share, but I didn't need that. You don't get a `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file using this method, this is an alternative to the other answers.